# Qt creator: No valid kits

Tags: qtcreator

Добавляю руками, компилятор, дебагер и прочее, но в qt version не знаю что ставить. Читал что надо qmake, но его нет в qtcreator. Где его отдельно скачать?
Win7.

Comment: Скачайте инсталлятор с сайта qt.io. При установке просто выберите подходящую версию qt + компилятор (там есть под студии разной битности и mingw). Если все выбрали правильно, qtcreator все найдет сам.

Comment: Да, всё разрешилось. По какой-то причине он не находил автоматом кит.